# Decoding a bitmap returns null

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to decode a bitmap but the function returns null and I don't know why.

The code:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if(requestCode == SELECT_FOTO) 
{
  Uri imgselect = data.getData();
  String imgpath = imgselect.getPath();
  File f = new File (imgpath);
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
  Toast.makeText(Insertarlugar.this, "Bitmap es" + bm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The toast indicates me that bm is null. I changed f.getAbsolutePath() for f.getPath() but the result is the same. Uri imgselect and String imgpath have values. I don't use SD card and I obtain the bitmap from gallery.

How can I resize the bitmap?

Thanks.

Comment: check the imgpath value first

Comment: As I said in my post, I checked imgselect value. Is content/media/external/images/media/11295, so it has value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one and check before imagepath is not null

```
Uri imgselect = data.getData();
String imgpath = imgselect.getPath();
if(imgpath !=null)
{
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgpath);
}
```

if the image have in large the it can not decode the imagepath so you try this and give the width and height as 60 and 60

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) {

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        return bmp;
        }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
             }
         }
         return inSampleSize;
        }
```

Comment: I fixed the problem. I didn't display the image on the screen. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Perfect Solution...Worked for me.

Comment: @sunil kumar can you please solve me this problem almost same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868432/how-to-set-image-in-imageview-choosing-file-from-gallery-and-giving-null-except?noredirect=1#comment74772806_43868432

Answer (score 0):

No need to use an actual file because you are referring to a Content Provider (which will do this for you)

```
Uri imgselect = data.getData();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgselect.getPath());
```

Cannot check if it works, you may need to decode the Uri first.

Comment: I tried what you typed but it doesn't run. I obtain null decoding bitmap. I decoded the Uri but the result is the same. I am stuck.